# I'm using Tkinter to create a shape and my goal is to continuously move the shape to the right of canvas until off screen ( AND REPEAT)

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

Forgive the lack of documentation. I'm a novice, so my code isn't the best, but I always appreciate positive feedback. So my problem is trying to get the shape to return to the original starting position after appearing off canvas and to continuously repeat the process. Any suggestions? Also, is there a way I could bind the up and down arrow keys to increase/decrease the shape's speed?

```
#import all from tkinter module
from tkinter import *

#create RacingCar class        
class RACECAR:
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        window = Tk()
        window.title("Racing Car")
        self.x = 1
        self.y = 0

        self.canvas = Canvas(window, width = 1200, height = 400, bg = "white")
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.displayCar()


        window.mainloop()

    def displayCar(self):
        
        self.body = self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 300, 150, 350, tags = "rect", \
            fill = "black")
        self.wheel1 = self.canvas.create_oval(100, 350, 150, 400, tags = "oval", \
            fill = "black")
        self.wheel2 = self.canvas.create_oval(0, 350, 50, 400, tags = "oval", \
            fill = "black")
        self.hood = self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 250, 100, 300, tags = "rect", \
            fill = "black")
        self.movement()


    def movement(self):
       
        self.canvas.move(self.body, self.x, self.y)
        
        self.canvas.move(self.wheel1, self.x, self.y)
        
        self.canvas.move(self.wheel2, self.x, self.y)
        
        self.canvas.move(self.hood, self.x, self.y)
        
        self.canvas.after(100, self.movement)


RACECAR()
```

Comment: To increase/decrease the speed just bind to the arrows and change `self.x` and `self.y`. For the looping part, detect when the objects are outside of the canvas' range and use `self.canvas.move(..., -1200, 0)` to move the object to the left by `1200` pixels

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I can't seem to figure out how to keep the object from going outside of the canvas range though. I've tried a few different loops but they aren't working. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach a common tag to the four items of the car, then

- save the starting position of the car using the common tag
- move the car using the common tag instead of moving each of the items
- check whether the car is out of canvas by checking the first value of `canvas.coords(...)`, if yes move the car back to its starting position

```py
def displayCar(self):
    # assign common tag "car" to items
    self.body = self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 300, 150, 350, tags="car rect", fill="black")
    self.wheel1 = self.canvas.create_oval(100, 350, 150, 400, tags="car oval", fill="black")
    self.wheel2 = self.canvas.create_oval(0, 350, 50, 400, tags="car oval", fill="black")
    self.hood = self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 250, 100, 300, tags="car rect", fill="black")
    # save the starting position
    self.start_pos = self.canvas.coords("car")[:2] 
    self.movement()

def movement(self):
    self.canvas.move("car", self.x, self.y)
    bbox = self.canvas.coords("car")
    if bbox[0] > 1200:
        # car moved out of canvas, so restart at starting position
        self.canvas.moveto("car", self.start_pos[0], self.start_pos[1])
    self.canvas.after(100, self.movement)
```

For adjusting the speed, you can bind on `<Up>` and `<Down>`, and update `self.x` inside the callback:

```py
def __init__(self):
    ...
    self.inc_x = 1   # adjust the value to suit your case
    window.bind('<Up>', lambda e: self.set_speed(+self.inc_x))
    window.bind('<Down>', lambda e: self.set_speed(-self.inc_x))
    ...

def set_speed(self, inc):
    self.x += inc
    # make sure self.x is at least 1 (or other value you want)
    if self.x < 1:
        self.x = 1
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help acw1668! I really appreciate it. I tried so many ways to set/reset the starting position and same goes for the arrow commands...that was a huge help. And the tip for using a common tag to move the entire piece rather than individually made way more sense. Thanks again!